# Web Unit Tests not finding Url

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, aspnetboilerplate

I am using aspnetboilerplate 5.1.0.

In the `ProjectName.Web.Tests` I have run into a situation that I cannot solve.

I have set up web tests for my controller using `[Fact]` or `[Theory]`.
When I attempt to run the tests using `GetResponseAsString(string url, HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK)` found in the webtestbase class. All the tests fail.

Here is an example of my Test:

```
     [Fact]
    public async Task Index_Test()
    {

        //Act
        var response = await GetResponseAsStringAsync(
            GetUrl<HomeController>(nameof(HomeController.Index))
        );

        //Assert
        response.ShouldNotBeNullOrEmpty();
    }
```

The Tests all fail on this:

```
Message: 
    Shouldly.ShouldAssertException : response.StatusCode
        should be
    HttpStatusCode.OK
        but was
    HttpStatusCode.NotFound
```

I have other aspnetboilerplate projects in version 3.8.3 and 4.2.1 and the web tests work just fine.  So I'm not sure why the server is not able to find the action methods on my controllers.

The service tests found in the `ProjectName.Tests` project run just fine.

Comment: You have not provided a lot of information regarding your environment and at the moment you’re assuming that everyone is an expert in the differences between aspnet boilerplate templates. Show us more code: what does the controller look like? What does the GetResponseAsString() method do? Are you running the test host server and can you access it in a browser if you hit a breakpoint? Update your question and if you find an answer post it and mark it as answered 24h later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit. The problem I was experiencing was due to attempting to copy a project for web unit tests from one of the aspnetboilerplate project template repositories and updating all of the references and class names to match the names and namespaces in the destination VS solution.

I submitted a similar question on the aspnetboilerplate github account. 
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/5463.

Ultimately, here is what happened.

After going through the same process with a newer project. I found that In the 
class file that would by default be named `AbpProjectNameWebTestBase.cs` in the method 
`protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
        {
            return base
                .CreateWebHostBuilder()
                .UseContentRoot(ContentRootFolder.Value)
                .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.ApplicationKey, typeof(AbpProjectNameWebModule).Assembly.FullName);
        }`

I mistakenly replaced `AbpProjectNameWebModule` with `AbpProjectNameTestModule` instead of `AbpProjectNameWebMvcModule`. This was trying to use the Application Service Unit test project as the web project. Therefore it could not find any of the referenced URI's and therefore returned `httpStatusCode.NotFound`.

After fixing this reference. I started getting exceptions that pertained to the `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)` method.

These were things like adding `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()` as well as needing to add a Middleware to provide a ClaimsIdentity  and ClaimsPrincipal for the context.User  (i.e. `app.UserMiddleware<TestAuthenticationMiddleware>()`)

Now, I am able to get my web unit tests to run as I had in previous versions.